# Symfony send mail error (Mailer and SwiftMailer)

Tags: docker, symfony, swiftmailer, mailer

I'm trying to send emails in my Symfony 4.4 app, I tryed both Mailer and SwiftMailer.

The app is running inside a Docker container, with shared ports 80 and 3306.

If I try the console command with SwiftMailer I get this:

```
bin/console swiftmailer:email:send --from=ex@example.com --to=ex@example.com --subject=hi --body=hi
```

> [OK] 1 emails were successfully sent.

And after a while I get:

> ERROR     [app] Exception occurred while flushing email queue: Expected response code 250 but got code "554", with message "554 5.2.0 STOREDRV.Submission.Exception:SendAsDeniedException.MapiExceptionSendAsDenied; Failed to process message due to a permanent exception with message Cannot submit message. [Hostname=XXXX.eurprd04.prod.outlook.com]

This happens with other email providers also, and both, in Mailer and SwiftMailer.

The fact that I get an (error) response from the service provider (Outlook in this case) makes me think that is not a port problem, as the email did actually reach the provider.

Any ideas? I'm quite stuck on this.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an outlook365 issue, your authentication account is different to the `From` address, this is forbidden unless you explicitly grant permission to do so.

You can easily solve this by using the same `From` address as the account you are using to authenticate. Otherwise, you'll need to [grant `SendAs` permission](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/admin/add-users/give-mailbox-permissions-to-another-user?view=o365-worldwide#send-email-from-another-users-mailbox) or `SendOnBehalf`.

Given your example, you need to set the permission on the `ex@example.com` mailbox, and grant it to the `authuser@example.com` user as configured in your `env`.

You need to do this for as many mailboxes as you want the `authuser` to be able to send mail as.

To check the configuration, you can access Office 365 as the `authuser` and try changing the `From` address when composing a new email. You should see all addresses that have granted permission to that user.

Comment: Setting "from" to the sender account solved the problem. Thank you.